# Can Meteor.js use a Node.js Library that is not available as a NPM Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I found a Node.js project repo on Github that among other files, contains a Node.js library containing several files. These files uses functions like `var util = require('./util');`

Placing these library files directly withing `/server/lib` causes the error

```
 /Users/username/.meteor/tools/7cf8f178ae/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
 ReferenceError: require is not defined
     at app/server/lib/address.js:1:49
     at app/server/lib/address.js:70:3
     at /Users/username/myApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/username/.meteor/tools/7cf8f178ae/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
     at /Users/username/myApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Whats the correct way of using node libraries like this that are not available as an npm package?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think it's doable at the moment. However you could always fork the repo, wrap it as a smart package and change module.exports = <package_name> to if(Meteor.isServer) {GLOBAL.<package_name> = <package_name> } else { window.<package_name> = <package_name>; That should work for most modules.

Comment: @Dave your suggestion seems to work to a certain extent! Currently facing a problem accessing a file in the parent directory using ` `Npm.require` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499588/meteor-npm-require-cannot-find-a-file-in-parent-directory

Comment: @Nyxynyx I'm also looking to do this, except I want to make changes to the NPM library and check it out as a submodule. Is it possible to do this or must I do the awkward tarball thing?