# Meteor Npm.require() cannot find a file in parent directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I'm trying to get an abandoned nodejs library to work under Meteor.

Why does `Npm.require('./crypto-js/crypto')` work fine, but `Npm.require('../convert')` is throwing the error `Error: Cannot find module '../convert'`?

**/packages/myPackage/package.js**

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {

  var path = Npm.require('path');  
  api.add_files(path.join('convert.js'), 'server');
  api.add_files(path.join('crypto-js', 'crypto.js'), 'server');
  api.add_files(path.join('util.js'), 'server');


});
```

**/packages/myPackage/convert.js**

```
myFunc = function() {
    return true
}
```

**/packages/myPackage/util.js**

```
Crypto = Npm.require('./crypto-js/crypto');
```

**/packages/myPackage/crypto-js/crypto.js**

```
var conv = Npm.require('../convert')
```

Comment: missing package.json file in the directory convert.js resides in? EDIT: does Npm.require('../convert.js') work?

Comment: @Dave I have a `package.js` in the same directory as `convert.js`, is a `package.json` still required? Tried `Npm.require('../convert.js') ` but got the error `Error: Cannot find module '../convert.js'`

Comment: I don't think it's required assuming you name your directory convert or your file convert.js. If Npm.require('../convert.js') is not working, and there's a convert.js file in ../ then Meteor is not implementing require the same way as Node.

Comment: Any particular reason to use that abandoned library instead of the crypto* packages on Atmosphere? I've repackaged sha1, base64 etc. and it's easy to clone [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-crypto-sha1) and add more functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered to this on IRC but posting here for the reference.

The author wanted to use a fork of npm module hosted on GitHub. To import the npm module from certain repo and certain commit, we can use GitHub's tarball url.

- Create a smart package in /packages/package-name
- In /packages/package-name/package.js describe the package, add files, export variables
- add `Npm.depends` to package.js file looking like this:

  Npm.depends({'NPM-MODULE-NAME': "https://github.com/REPOAUTHOR/REPONAME/tarball/COMMIT-SHA1"});
- in one of the smart package's files do `ExportSymbol = Npm.require('NPM-MODULE-NAME')`
- export the export symbol

example: https://github.com/Slava/meteor-npm-fork-example

Comment: How do you do it if your node module isn't hosted on Github?

Comment: @Dave hmm, you can pass any url to a tarball with your module. If you want to keep your npm module on fs, I don't know such way yet

Comment: @imslavko, is there a way to `Npm.require` a submodule instead of doing it this way?